# Error when connecting to .mdf from ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, connection-string

When trying to connect to a .mdf databse in ASP.NET (using c#) I am given this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server.The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

Does this mean my connection string is wrong? What should it be?

Aside from that, I am very new to ASP.NET. I am trying to connect to this database in the same way I would in c# normally (using data adapters and SqlCommands). Is this the right way to go about it, or is there a different way? When I started a new website adding user accounts worked (there was a wizard or something?) but I couldn't work out how to add more user information. What is the best way to connect to an SQL database and add user accounts with login and personal details in ASP.NET?

**EDIT:** My Connection String is `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;User Instance=true`

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: I've added in the Connection String.

Comment: Is your SQL Server instance running?

Comment: Yes it is. I did pretty much an identical thing in C# to test that the SQL bits were working, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Did you try looking @ http://www.connectionstrings.com/ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've fixed it. For reference for anyone else:

The correct connection string was given in the `Web.config` file.
The connection string I needed was `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True`

Comment: Clearly it's not what I thought it might have been then - I was about to post an answer! What changed for it to start working? I can't see a difference between the connection string here and the one in your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite know. Just checked web.config and pasted it in.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your connection string properly, you're never specifying a **database** to use!

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
  AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Add the database to the connection string - and also, loose the extra backslash after the `|DataDirectory|`:

```
server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
  AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Users.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Comment: Is that file really there? Do you have permissions to read that file?